# WCF from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wcf

I am having a WCF service Hosted separately in IIS

I need it to consume from separate web application using JavaScript (client side) but my namespace is not recognized by JavaScript intellisense.

When I browse my service it works fine.

Is that any reference needed to be given to the .svc?

Comment: Please say where your JavaScript is located. Is this an ASP.NET application? MVC? Have you added a script reference to the service?

Comment: Can you think of any reason at all why intellisense should have known anything at all about your new service?

Answer (score 0):

"Please say where your JavaScript is located. Is this an ASP.NET application? MVC? Have you added a script reference to the service?"

Is that script reference to service is necessary ?? do u mean to give service reference in
script manager or script reference ?????

in many forums they have not specified about script reference to WCF service .
how to give it???????

Comment: Thanks for coming back. I wish you would answer my questions. What kind of web application is this? ASP.NET Web Forms, or ASP.NET MVC?